# в чем различие localdb (из состава VS) и oracal express?

Tags: c#, sql-server-localdb

Всем привет! Подскажите новичку, в чем различие localdb (из состава VS) и oracal express? Требуется написать тестовую задачку. Могу сделать на localdb, с oracal express никогда не работал, с ходу развернуть не получилось. Что нельзя с ходу использовать? Собираюсь использовать триггеры, внешние ключи и хранимые процедуры.

Comment: "Могу сделать на localdb" - в таком случае делайте на MS SQL LocalDB.

Comment: Различия не значительные?

Comment: Это две совершенно разные СУБД. И различия у них огромные. Но для учебных целей они непринципиальны. Берите любую.